# How to remove \r when pushing commits to Gerrit from Windows?

Tags: eclipse, git, gerrit

I and a colleague of mine work in Eclipse on Windows machines.

When I push my changes to Gerrit, there are \r marks in the source view.

[image: Gerrit]

When my colleague does the same, there are no such characters.

The git settings on both machines are equal to:

```
$ git config --global --get core.eol
native

$ git config --global --get core.autocrlf
false

$ git config --global --get core.whitespace
```

I'm using following Eclipse settings.

[image: Eclipse 1]

[image: Eclipse 2]

I tried to run `File -> Convert line delimiters to -> Windows`, but it didn't help (`git status` didn't show any modified files after I did this).

How can I make sure that when I commit my changes, there are no \r characters in Gerrit?

Comment: what version of gerrit are you using? this was reported as a bug (425) but i think it was fixed in 2.6

Comment: I'm using Gerrit 2.8.

Comment: according to the release notes of 2.5 it is an user prefence option - you should be able to turn it off

Comment: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/c/36630/

Comment: it'll be in the  .gitattributes file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \r is because windows line endings are \r\n (vs. unix line endings which are just \n)  You could switch to unix line endings but you would have to commit all the files.

Gerrit has an option to hide line endings, it's under preferences when you're in the source view.  This seems like the best option.

Comment: Where is preferences found? I can't find it, and I've Ctrl-f "preferences" on every page with source code visible.